# Javascript: Compare dates in different GMT offsets

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of dates and need to find today in that list, but the timezones are off. When I use let d = new Date() it returns GMT-6, but the list of dates are in GMT-7. I've looked all over and can't find out how to get the 2 dates such that d1 == d2 returns true.
This is on Google Sheets, so I know I can manipulate the timezones of the sheet and script, but I'd like to figure this out so that the script can run regardless of locale.

Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XKrH5AQSIGxJOWOzxT6OaI2ibn2kqeb9etyl5VGZu8M/edit#gid=0

```
function openToDate(){
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  let d = new Date();
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  let d1 = d.toUTCString();
  let d2;
  Logger.log(d);
  Logger.log(d.getTime());
  Logger.log(d1);
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i=i+6){
    Logger.log(i);
    d2 = new Date(data[i][0]);
    Logger.log(d2);
    Logger.log(d2.getTime());
  }
```

Comment: Convert them to a timezone-agnostic format, such as a UTC Date or an epoch timestamp.

Comment: @Abion47 I saw the .toISOString() method mentioned several times, but given that that converts it to a string, rather than a date object, it lost all usefulness. Is there a way to convert to UTC while remaining a date?

Comment: Time zone shouldn't really affect the "core" date. You're likely having an issue due to the dates being the same, but not the times. Are you able to confirm?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a direct conversion, but a quick and dirty way is to combine `toISOString` with `Date.parse`, or use the `getUTCX` functions to rebuild a Date object. Alternatively, I'd recommend using the moment and moment-timezone packages, but I don't know if you have that option in a Google Sheets script.

Comment: @Diego that's correct: they both show 10/21/20, but one is GMT-6 and the other is GMT-7

Comment: @Spencer What are the hour, minute, second parts of those dates?

Comment: @Diego I set it all to 0

Comment: @Spencer Can you post your code, please?

Comment: @Diego I edited the post to include the code and a link to the sheet, if helpful.

Comment: If you have two date objects set to `10/21/20` with all time components set to 0, but one is GMT-6 and the other is GMT-7, then they are not equal date objects. You can see this by converting them to UTC ISO-8601 timestamps, where the first will be "2020-10-21T**06**:00:00.000Z" and the second will be "2020-10-21T**07**:00:00.000Z". (Note the different hour values.)

Comment: @Abion47 I know, that's what I want to fix. I want to do something to set them equal.

Comment: What is the actual end goal here? To what purpose are you wanting to set two dates of differing timezones to be equal regardless of their respective timezone offsets?

Comment: I want to find the row at which today's date is found and then jump to that range. I found a workaround of just doing it if the difference between dates is less than 8000000

Comment: Use `getYear`, `getMonth`, and `getDate` to compare directly to the local time's date values.

Comment: What is your definition of "today"? Does it depend on local or UTC date? Typically offsets don't apply to date–only timestamps, only the date components are compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date equality, you'll want to use the numeric value of the date. When you call [`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), it will return that numeric value of the adjusted date. If you're having time zone issues, you can try using [`setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours).

```
function openToDate(){
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const today = (new Date()).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i=i+6){
    let d = (new Date(data[i][0])).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
    if (today == d) {
      Logger.log('MATCH!'); 
    }
  }
}
```